# rm command not executing via cron

Tags: linux, cron

Could anybody please let me know why my code is not executing via cron job. But the same perfectly executing when i run manually.

## cronjob

```
30 19 * * * /backup1/RMAN/dumpremoval.sh > /backup1/RMAN/dumpremoval.log2 2>&1
```

## CODE

```
cat /backup1/RMAN/dumpremoval.sh
yest=$(date --date='1 day ago' +"%y%y%m%d")
yestdump=SMARTDB_D_$yest
ls -lrt $yestdump* > /backup1/RMAN/dumpexists 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
rm -rf $yestdump*
fi
```

Here my intention is, i want to delete yesterday's backup files daily those are having file names 
like SMARTDB_D_20200409*

Thank you..

Comment: `cron` will run the job in your home directory.  Is that where your `SMARTDB_D_...` files are?  Also, replace `%y%y` with `%Y` if you want this script to keep working next year.

Comment: No sir. My backup files are NOT in home directory. Here my question is, when i run the script manually with /backup1/RMAN/dumpremoval.sh , Its perfectly executing and deleting the yesterday's file. But when i use cron, its not executing. Is there any limitation with cron for such scripts?

Comment: There's no limitation, but you have to adapt your script to the way `cron` is going to run it.  `cron` will launch the script with your home directory as its working directory.  If you want the script to operate on files in `/backup1/RMAN` then you must either specify that path on all filenames in the script, or you must have the script `cd` into that directory before it does `ls -lrt $yestdump`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your update sir. I'll modify the script as per your suggestion and will update you soon. Thank you..

Comment: Hi, I modified the script as you suggested. I added `cd` command in the script. now the script is `yest=$(date --date='1 day ago' +"%y%y%m%d")`
`export yestdump=SMARTDB_D_$yest`
`cd /backup1/RMAN`
`ls -lrt $yestdump* > /backup1/RMAN/dumpexists 2> /dev/null`
`if [ $? -eq 0 ]`
`then`
`rm -rf $yestdump*`
`fi`
i will check and let you know the status. Thank you

Comment: Hi ottomeister, Fentastic. your suggestion worked for me and the script is now successfully removing yesterday's dumps. i just added `cd /backup1/RMAN` in my script as you suggested. Its worked. Thank you very much